# Switch style plugin of a view based on results

Tags: views

I would like to create a view, which would display it's result with style plugin *Unformatted* if there is only 1 result, but would use *Bootstrap Accordion* style plugin, if there are more of them. I tried to do it like this:

```
    name == 'some_view_name') {
        if (count($view->result) > 1) {
          $view->style_plugin = 'ViewsBootstrapAccordionPluginStyle';
          $view->style_plugin->plugin_name = 'views_bootstrap_accordion_plugin_style';
          $view->style_plugin->options['title_field'] = 'title';
          $view->style_plugin->definition['path'] = 'sites/all/modules/views_bootstrap/plugins/accordion';
          $view->style_plugin->definition['theme path'] = 'sites/all/modules/views_bootstrap/templates/accordion';
          $view->style_plugin->definition['file'] = 'ViewsBootstrapAccordionPluginStyle.inc';
          $view->style_plugin->definition['theme file'] = 'theme.inc';

        }
      }
    }
```

The result is this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object in .../sites/all/modules/views/theme/theme.inc on line 49`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Probably almost everything. `$view->style_plugin` has to be an object, that was the reason of the error above. So I modified the code to this:

```
<?php
function my_module_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'my_view') {
    if (count($view->result) > 1) {
      $bs_accordion_style = new ViewsBootstrapAccordionPluginStyle;
      $bs_accordion_style->plugin_name = 'views_bootstrap_accordion_plugin_style';
      $bs_accordion_style->options['title_field'] = 'title';
      $bs_accordion_style->definition['path'] = 'sites/all/modules/views_bootstrap/plugins/accordion';
      $bs_accordion_style->definition['theme path'] = 'sites/all/modules/views_bootstrap/templates/accordion';
      $bs_accordion_style->definition['file'] = 'ViewsBootstrapAccordionPluginStyle.inc';
      $bs_accordion_style->definition['theme file'] = 'theme.inc';
      $bs_accordion_style->options['grouping'] = array();
      $bs_accordion_style->row_plugin = $view->style_plugin->row_plugin;
      $bs_accordion_style->definition['theme'] = 'views_bootstrap_accordion_plugin_style';
      $bs_accordion_style->view = $view->style_plugin->view;
      $bs_accordion_style->display = $view->style_plugin->display;
      $view->style_plugin = $bs_accordion_style;
      $view->style_options['title_field'] = 'title';
    }
  }
}
```

That almost works. It results in this error (1 per view result):

`Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in include() (line 21 of .../sites/all/modules/views_bootstrap/templates/accordion/views-bootstrap-accordion-plugin-style.tpl.php)`

How can I correct this?

Comment: Have you checked if style class exists in a file you are claiming it to be? And with that exact name?

Comment: The reasoning above is most probably completely wrong, as `$view->style_plugin` has to be an object, not a string. I got further and will edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: Hope I helped, even if only by pointing you in right direction - because I admit I failed to spot string <-> object issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally discovered a workaround, that may be the solution for some. I display the view using Panels. Using *visibility rule*, there is possibility to limit visibility of view based on number of results of that view. The steps could be:

1. Create a *Contextual filter* for your view for field `Content:Nid`. This should correspond to argument of your *Ctools Page* (so that path of a page is similar to `something/%nid`). You may need to add Relationship, if you want to display content, that is related to the content with `nid`.
2. Create a *Context* display for your view.
3. Create a 2 separate displays (*Content panes*) for your view - for one result and multiple results.
4. Create a new *Relationship* based on your view for your Panel (at the *Contexts* tab).
5. Add **both** your *content panes* to the panel.
6. Add *Visibility rules* to both panes. You should choose PHP-based filtering and enter something like:

`if (count($contexts['relationship_view_from_argument:name-of-your-view-ctools_context_1_1']->output['rows'])==1) {`
`return TRUE;`
`}`